# plotting randint function result give me unexpected plot in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I write a code that generates a random number between (0, 10) 100000 time and plot it, I expect the histogram to be flat but this what I got

```
import random 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numbers = []
for i in range(10000000):
    numbers.append(random.randint(0, 10))

plt.hist(numbers)
```

[image]

Comment: Use a small integer like 10-20, for range... Then print the number array, and share with us..

Comment: Short answer: you used default bins. Distribution is fine. This is why there's a whole area of research on how best to comute histogram bins.